# android NullPointerException when adding a floating banner into customized adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, banner

When adding a banner after each 12 items of a listView, the listView work fine if an advertisement banner is fix but when i include floating banner.

**Logcat:**

```
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:383)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11315)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4314)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1625)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
07-01 10:36:00.352: E/AndroidRuntime(31771):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**class adapter:**

```
 public MyAdapter(Activity context, ImageManager imageManager) {
    this.context = context;


    annoncesList.clear();
    bannersPositionSet.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return annoncesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    int div = position / 12;
    int restDiv = position % 12;

    if (restDiv == div - 1)
        return (String) annoncesList.get(position);
    else
        return (Annonce) annoncesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (bannersPositionSet.contains(position))
    {
        return TYPE_BANNER;
    }
    else
        return TYPE_ANNONCE;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return TYPE_COUNT; // Count of different layouts
}

public void addBannerItem()
{
    annoncesList.add("banner");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    // save banner position
    bannersPositionSet.add(annoncesList.size() - 1);

}

public void addAllAnnonceItems(List<Annonce> annonceList)
{
    annoncesList.addAll(annonceList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearList()
{
    annoncesList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Destroy all banners to free memory
 * 
 * this method is used in the method: onDestroy of activity annonceList
 */
public void destroyBanner()
{
    for (SASBannerView banner : bannerList)
    {
        banner.onDestroy();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type)
        {
            case TYPE_ANNONCE:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.annonce_row, null);

                viewHolder.annonceImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_image);
                viewHolder.annonceTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_title);
                viewHolder.annonceAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_seller_city);
                viewHolder.annoncePrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_price);
                viewHolder.annonceEuroSymbole = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.euro_symbole);
                viewHolder.annonceFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_flag);
                viewHolder.annonceDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.annonce_date);

                viewHolder.annonceTitle.setTypeface(tfLatoBol);
                viewHolder.annonceAddress.setTypeface(tfLatoReg);
                viewHolder.annoncePrice.setTypeface(tfLatoBol);
                viewHolder.annonceEuroSymbole.setTypeface(tfLatoBol);
                viewHolder.annonceDate.setTypeface(tfLatoReg);
            break;

            case TYPE_BANNER:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_android_banner, null);
                viewHolder.floatingBannerView = (SASBannerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.floating_banner);

                final SASBannerView sasBannerView = viewHolder.floatingBannerView;

                floatingBannerResponseHandler = new SASAdView.AdResponseHandler()
                {
                    public void adLoadingCompleted(SASAdElement adElement)
                    {
                        DebugLog.i(TAG, "floating Banner loading completed");
                        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                sasBannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    public void adLoadingFailed(Exception e)
                    {
                        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                sasBannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        DebugLog.i(TAG, "floating Banner loading failed: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                };

            break;
            default:
            break;

        }
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (type == TYPE_BANNER)
    {
        loadFloatingBannerView(viewHolder.floatingBannerView, floatingBannerResponseHandler);
        bannerList.add(viewHolder.floatingBannerView);
    }
    else if (type == TYPE_ANNONCE)
    {
        Annonce annonce = (Annonce) this.getItem(position);
        viewHolder.annonceTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(annonce.getTitle()));
            }
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * 
 * Load floating banner view
 * 
 */
private void loadFloatingBannerView(SASBannerView floatingBanner,
        SASAdView.AdResponseHandler floatingBannerResponseHandler)
{
    // load floating banner ad with appropriate parameters
    // (siteID,pageID,formatID,master,targeting,adResponseHandler)
    floatingBanner.loadAd(Constants.BANNER_BETWEEN_ANNONCES_SITE_ID, Constants.BANNER_BETWEEN_ANNONCES_PAGE_ID,
            Constants.BANNER_BETWEEN_ANNONCES_FORMAT_ID, true, Constants.BANNER_BETWEEN_ANNONCES_TARGET,
            floatingBannerResponseHandler);
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView annonceImage;
    public TextView annonceTitle;
    public TextView annonceAddress;
    public TextView annoncePrice;
    public TextView annonceEuroSymbole;
    public ImageView annonceFlag;
    public TextView annonceDate;
    public SASBannerView floatingBannerView;
}

}
```

Comment: i have updated my post with my java code.

Comment: pls point out the line where the exception comes .